# What are the top professional organizations that philosophers belong to?

Tags: reference-request

I looked for a [list of philosophical organizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_philosophical_organizations) and found this list on Wikipedia.

What are the top or most prestigious organizations on this list (or some other list) that a professional philosopher would expect their peers to be aware of if not members of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the USA the American Philosophical Association, which has Eastern, Central and Pacific Divisions. In the UK the Aristotelian Society and the Mind Association. Non-professionals can join the two latter but professionals dominate it. There's also, but not on your list, the Institute of Philosophy at the Institute of Advanced Studies at University of London.

(https://www.apaonline.org/general/custom.asp?page=pj_jfp)

Comment: I suggested an edit to supply context for your claims. I apologize if the suggestion was too bold.

Comment: @Tautological Revelations. I agreed the edit, which was referred to me. I appreciate anything that makes answers more helpful. So thank you - Best : Geoffrey

Comment: Cheers! Let me know if you need any other futher sources and/or similar references for this answer. :)

Comment: The Australasian Association of Philosophy is another major anglophone society.

Comment: @ChristopherE. Thanks for this. I did know of the AAP but for whatever reason it didn't come to mind. I have included your comment in my answer, with acknowledgement. I hope this is OK. One role of comments, as I see it, is to strengthen answers. Much appreciated : GT