# Are there any well known academic philosophy forums?

Tags: reference-request

Apart from Philosophy Stack Exchange (PSE), are there any well known academic philosophy forums?

PSE does not seem to me as active as MathSE or PhysicsSE.

That's the reason I'm asking the question above.

Comment: there's some email lists you could find?

Comment: 'DailyNous' is one. It offers a fascinating insight into the profession. Not really a forum though and more a bulletin board. . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Reddit group, [r/askphilosophpy](https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/top/), that may be of interest:  It claims to have as of this writing 101 thousand members with 247 online.

Stack Exchanges, however, should not be viewed as academic forums. They are primarily question and answer sites and not forums for discussion. There are, however, chat rooms where discussions can take place. Also, anyone may ask and answer questions. Activity is not restricted to academics or professionals.

For interaction with professional philosophers there are organizations that may offer what one desires.  Geoffrey Thomas lists some in [his answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/52950/29944) to an earlier question:

> In the USA the American Philosophical Association, which has Eastern, Central and Pacific Divisions. In the UK the Aristotelian Society and the Mind Association. Non-professionals can join the two latter but professionals dominate it. There's also, but not on your list, the Institute of Philosophy at the Institute of Advanced Studies at University of London.